# The trace of a multilinear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

Say we have $f \in \operatorname{End}(V^{\otimes n})$ for a vector space $V$ with basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_m\}$. Then, given $i_1,i_2,....i_n \in \{1,2,...,m\}$ we have:

$$f(v_{i_1} \otimes v_{i_2} \otimes ... \otimes v_{i_n}) = \sum_{1 \leq j_1,\dots,j_m \leq m}f^{j_1,\dots,j_{n}}_{i_1,\dots,i_{n}}v_{j_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes v_{j_n}.$$

Is the following
$$\operatorname{tr}(f) = \sum_{1 \leq j_1,\dots,j_m \leq m}f^{j_1,\dots,j_{n}}_{j_1,\dots,j_{n}}$$
the correct expression for the trace of $f$?
If not, then what is?

Also, is there a difference between the "operator trace", "partial trace", and "quantum trace"? I have not yet noticed a difference. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the first question: yes, your expression for the trace of $f$ is correct.  Regarding the second: the [partial trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_trace) is explained a bit here. Note that the partial trace of an operator is an endomorphism on a smaller space rather than a scalar. I'm not sure about the other two terms

Comment: From googling, the "operator trace" seems to refer simply to the trace map as defined for [endomorphisms of a Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class#Definition). I can't find any mention of a "quantum trace".